# get into next screen after google login

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

I just wanted to navigate to the next screen after I log in to the google account. What and where do I have to implement the required code below to navigate to the next screen after google account login ?

```
    class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget  {
      final controller= Get.put(googleLogin());
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return
           Scaffold(
            body: Container(
            
                 **Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children:[
                              GestureDetector(
                     child: Image.asset(
                       "assets/images/google_logo.png",
                       width: 40,
                     ),
                     onTap: () async {
                       controller.signIn();**
    
                     }),

 GestureDetector(
                 child: Image.asset(
                   "assets/images/fb_logo.png",
                   width: 40,
                 ),
                 onTap: () {

                 }),
               SizedBox(
                 width: 15,
               ),
             GestureDetector(
                 child: Image.asset(
                   "assets/images/apple_logo.png",
                   width: 40,
                 ),
                 onTap: () {

                 }),
               
          
        );
      }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: After your on tap controller.signIn(); you can naviagte to another screen

Comment: You can use `Get.to(NextScreen());` or `Get.off(NextScreen());` depending on your situation. You will have to place this login inside a function that will be triggered once once the user is logged in after tapping the 'Google login button'.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to another screen if the user login is successful like below. You need to set the return type of the `controller.signIn` function as a `Future<bool>`.

```dart
onTap: () async {
  final didLogin = await controller.signIn();
  if (didLogin) {
    Get.to(() => NextScreen());
  }
}),
```

Comment: Thanks.But the problem is I am getting a black thick line moving from top to bottom after logins